# Parse an HTML tag on Android

Tags: android, html, parsing

How can I parse an HTML input tag to extract its value on Android?
Here is the example of an HTML page where I would extract the value in the tag:

`<input type="hidden" name="logged-in" value="yes" >`

```html
<form name='connect' action='http://url.net/' method='post'>
  <input type="hidden" name="pageOrigine" value="alogin"><br/>
  <input type="hidden" name="hostname" value="0.0.0.0"><br/>
  <input type="hidden" name="identity" value="XXXXXXX"><br/>
  <input type="hidden" name="login-by" value=""><br/>
  <input type="hidden" name="server-address" value="0.0.0.0:80"><br/>
  <input type="hidden" name="server-name" value="XXXXXXXXX"><br/>
  <input type="hidden" name="inter-name" value="XXXXXXXXXX"><br/>
  <input type="hidden" name="ip" value="0.0.0.0"><br/>
  <input type="hidden" name="domain" value=""><br/>
  <input type="hidden" name="logged-in" value="yes">
  <input type="hidden" name="username" value=""><br/>
  <input type="hidden" name="host-ip" value="0.0.0.0"><br/>
  <input type="hidden" name="session-time-left" value=""><br/>
  <input type="hidden" name="uptime" value="0s"><br/>
  <input type="hidden" name="link-orig" value=""><br/>
  <input type="hidden" name="link-status" value="http://0.0.0.0/stat"><br/>
  <input type="hidden" name="link-logout" value="http://0.0.0.0/logout"><br/>
  <input type="hidden" name="link-login-only" value="http://0.0.0.0/login"><br/>
  <input type="hidden" name="bytes-in-nice" value="0 B"><br/>
  <input type="hidden" name="bytes-out-nice" value="0 B"><br/>
  <input type="hidden" name="bytes-in" value="0"><br/>
  <input type="hidden" name="bytes-out" value="0"><br/>
  <input type="hidden" name="error" value=""><br/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in JavaScript with the **[`getElementsByName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName)** method. Keep in mind that this returns a **[NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)** collection of elements, so you'll want to return the first result with `[0]`:

```js
var target = document.getElementsByName('logged-in')[0];
console.log(target.value);
```

```html
<form name='connect' action='http://url.net/' method='post'>
  <input type="hidden" name="pageOrigine" value="alogin"><br/>
  <input type="hidden" name="hostname" value="0.0.0.0"><br/>
  <input type="hidden" name="identity" value="XXXXXXX"><br/>
  <input type="hidden" name="login-by" value=""><br/>
  <input type="hidden" name="server-address" value="0.0.0.0:80"><br/>
  <input type="hidden" name="server-name" value="XXXXXXXXX"><br/>
  <input type="hidden" name="inter-name" value="XXXXXXXXXX"><br/>
  <input type="hidden" name="ip" value="0.0.0.0"><br/>
  <input type="hidden" name="domain" value=""><br/>
  <input type="hidden" name="logged-in" value="yes">
  <input type="hidden" name="username" value=""><br/>
  <input type="hidden" name="host-ip" value="0.0.0.0"><br/>
  <input type="hidden" name="session-time-left" value=""><br/>
  <input type="hidden" name="uptime" value="0s"><br/>
  <input type="hidden" name="link-orig" value=""><br/>
  <input type="hidden" name="link-status" value="http://0.0.0.0/stat"><br/>
  <input type="hidden" name="link-logout" value="http://0.0.0.0/logout"><br/>
  <input type="hidden" name="link-login-only" value="http://0.0.0.0/login"><br/>
  <input type="hidden" name="bytes-in-nice" value="0 B"><br/>
  <input type="hidden" name="bytes-out-nice" value="0 B"><br/>
  <input type="hidden" name="bytes-in" value="0"><br/>
  <input type="hidden" name="bytes-out" value="0"><br/>
  <input type="hidden" name="error" value=""><br/>
</form>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

1) You can use DOM Parser and compare the value of `name` attribute. [Here is a tutorial](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/).

2) You can also use [JAXB](https://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/).

3) You can use [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/), especially if you are scraping a webpage.